# Set ID attribute with Google's Map API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to make code which will put icon on Google Map and ID(HTML ID). I do little code for test, I get alert message but icon doesn't hide. Why?

```
var _hSync_ikona_dolara = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(1320.7709, -891.5645),
    map: map,
    icon: '_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_map_icons/_hsync_map_dollar.gif',
    id: 'testid' // THIS!
});

$('#_test').click(function()
{
    alert("e");
    $('#testid').hide();
});
```

So, when user click on `_test` ID(text, button whatever...), all icons with id `testid` should hide.

**EDIT:** I found this

```
var _hSync_ikona_dolara = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(1320.7709, -891.5645),
    map: map,
    icon: '_hsync_style/_hsync_images/_hsync_map_icons/_hsync_map_dollar.gif'
});
_hSync_ikona_dolara.metadata = { id: 'testid' };
```

It doesn't work, question was posted six years ago.

Comment: Does somebody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reading through the docs where it goes through setting event listeners, as this will help you trigger other functionality with markers.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what You link can help me.